# How to export JTree data as XML file by using JDOM

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jdom-2

I have a jtree and need to save each child level element save as xml, I tried to using below code to implement it, but it gives errors for converting numeric data of the xml document,

Error message :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jdom2.IllegalNameException: The name "1001" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML name '1001' cannot begin with the character "1".
    at org.jdom2.Element.setName(Element.java:227)
    at org.jdom2.Element.<init>(Element.java:161)
    at org.jdom2.Element.<init>(Element.java:173)
```

error pointed to, **Element el = new Element(node.toString());**

what may be the cause to the error?

```
// Save the XML file which has been modified.
    private void saveMsg(TreeModel model) {     
            FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("xml files (*.xml)","xml");
            fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(""));
            fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Save XML file");            

            if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                //File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                TreeModel tModel = xmlTree.getModel();              
                int childCount = tModel.getChildCount(tModel.getRoot());
                logger.info("Messages to be sent : " + childCount);

                for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++){
                    // go through each xml messages.
                    jtree2Xml(tModel.getChild(tModel.getRoot(), i)); 
                }                   
            }       
    } // End of Save XML file.  


    private void jtree2Xml(Object node) {           
            Document doc = new Document();          
            Element root = createTree(doc, xmlTree.getModel(), node);               
            doc.addContent(root);           
            XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());              
            try {
                out.output(doc, System.out);
                out.output(doc, new FileWriter(file));
                System.out.println("Saved the xml file...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Xml file saving error : ");
            }
    } // End of the method.



    // Read through the document's elements.
    private static Element createTree(Document doc, TreeModel model, Object node) {         
        **Element el = new Element(node.toString());**          
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getChildCount(node); i++) {           
            Object child = model.getChild(node, i);
            el.addContent(createTree(doc, model, child));           
        } // End of the while loop.
        return el;
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, of course

Comment: I find it odd you should reply *"of course"* when you did not post an SSCCE and there is no edit with an SSCCE now.

Answer (score 0):

the message from JDOM is very clear. The Element name cannot start with the character '1'. This comes from the XML spec http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#NT-NameStartChar

you should use a fixed name for the Element, and put the JTree node toString in an Attribute.

```
 <jtreenode value="1001"/>
```

Rolfl

Comment: can you see any misleading point in the logic of createTree()? It seems like the logic is incorrect to read jtree nodes and convert them into xml file.